# How to combine 2 columns from database in DropDownList c# OleDb

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I want to get from my database two columns and to put it in my DropDownList but when I write this code the software give me error message:"Data Association: System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal not contain a property named 'ProductManufacturer ProductModel'." and put the "ProductsList.DataBind();" in red color.
What is the problem and how can I show ProductManufacturer & ProductModel in the DropDownList.

```
        OleDbConnection con11 = new OleDbConnection();
        con11.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("") + "\\DataBases.accdb";
        con11.Open();
        string sql1 = "select * from ProductsTable";
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql1, con11);
        OleDbDataReader Dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        ProductsList.DataSource =Dr1;
        ProductsList.DataTextField = "ProductManufacturer" + " " + "ProductModel";
        ProductsList.DataValueField = "ProductModel";
        ProductsList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine them in your query.

```
string sql1 = "select *, ProductManufacturer + ' ' + ProductModel as someField  from ProductsTable";

ProductsList.DataTextField = "someField";
```